# Post Data to JSNOP enabled WCF Service Using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, wcf, jsonp

Is it possible to post data to a WCF Service using JSONP?  I need JSONP due to same origin policy flexibility.

For example, I have a the following WCF Service:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 bool SetRate(string Id, string name, double Rate);
```

Or does it need to be:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 bool SetRating(string UserId, string MovieId, double Rating);
```

Then on the client side:

```
 $.getJSON('http://test:1000/WebServices.svc/jsonp/SetRate/ABC/DEF/22?callback=?', null, function (r) {
                 alert('Received ' + r.toString());
             });
```

Or do I need to do a $.postJSON(...)?

Or am I way off?  Is this even possible?  I was able to successfully call (get) a WCF Service using JSONP.  This test was a simple "get".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see this post

[Posting from JQuery to WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481618/posting-from-jquery-to-wcf-service)